# Receive like, share notification from Facebook App on my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I try to receive all notification, when someone like or share an article on my website.

So, on my website, I initialize FB (I use FB Connect)

```
  FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxx',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      cookie     : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
```

and this Like (and share) button

```
   <div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

And is there a paramater to pass into the `FB.init` like `pageId`or what ?
I have the date into my App Insight, but just numbers ... I can't know which one of my website is more liked, or shared ...

Thank by advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the "edge.create" event with `FB.Event.subscribe`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.1

For example:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (url, html_element) {
    console.log(url);
    console.log(html_element);
});
```

Just put this right after `FB.init`.

---

In the callback function, you can make an AJAX call to store the likes in your database, for example.

Comment: Oh ok thank you. So I wont, never, receive notification to my Facebook Page. It's annoying.

Comment: sure, it´s possible, with the code i posted...you can do whatever you want in the callback function.